# Android place a button 1/4 of the way down the screen

Tags: android, xml, button

[image: What I am trying to do]

Assuming the yellow line is the center line and the black lines are the halfway point between the yellow and the top.  The Red boxes represent where I would like to place the buttons.  I'm not sure how to define these locations or make the buttons be centered on them instead of above or below them.  I would prefer to do it in the xml as opposed to from the java, but I will if I need to.  Maybe it has something to do with android:weight. Thanks

Comment: I just made a change to my answer. I removed unnecessary `LinearLayout` code still works well. Check my edited answer and you can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this xml file. It will show you buttons at the position you have described in your question. It works for any screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why such a **high nesting level**? It's really a **bad design**. Just put two buttons in the root LinearLayout...

Comment: yeah I made a change now, see my edited answer now. @DerGolem

Comment: Either Chrome doesn't update or I still see two **unnecessary** RelativeLayouts

Comment: @DerGolem How can you create such layout only by **putting two buttons in LinearLayout SIR???**

Comment: You can. Use generic Views (as vertical spacers) and **weights**.

Comment: @DerGolem Ever wondered how giving space will work in same way for all screen sizes!?!?!?

Comment: It will work **perfectly** in all resolutions, since **weights** work in **proportion**.

Comment: @DerGolem: indeed. a few spacer views with weights should do. Why don't you write it down as an answer (apparently that would be the only way Apurva will ever believe it)? (anyway, this extra level of nesting gives a little more readability, imho, and I don't see that as such a bad design)

Comment: @DerGolem: and by `percent` you mean `proportion`

Comment: Yes, which in some occasions coincide (if you use weights such as 25 for 1/4, 75 for 3/4)...

Comment: @DerGolem and if you tell me to create with only one `LinearLayout` then where would you give weight hun? If you give in button tag the button will occupy half of screen size. Your idea is never gonna work

Comment: @Apurva: **njzk2 understood perfectly** what I had in mind. OK, `I'm probably a bit fixed`, but I always try to get the **flattest** design possible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (omitting the verbose attributes):

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Edit

Since apparently no one will do it:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button ... />
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    <Button ... />
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add the necessary attributes to the button, and that should be it.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the RelativeLayouts.

Comment: the `centerInParent` only works inside RelativeLayout. It could possibly be replaced by a good use of gravity.

Comment: @DerGolem: The only thing with this solution is that it requires the buttons to be the exact same height. (which is not the case for the RelativeLayout solution)

Comment: Yeah! great, @njzk2. That's the **flattest** design I had in mind.

Comment: @DerGolem: flat is good, but I find that the RelativeLayout option does a better job a carrying the idea of a screen split in **2** halves, each of them having a button in its **center**

Comment: I prefer `performances` to easy concept. OK **very small** performance increase. But... today it has become a mind-shape for me... Optimize! Optimize! It's a MANTRA.